# Firebase gives permission denied error while writing to db in android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have set permissions.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
}
```

in firebase db.
First i am authorising the user in firebase then trying to enter a row to my firebase table.
i am getting permission denied error.

using below code to insert data to firebase table

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersProfile");
mDatabase.child(key).setValue(userProfile);
```

Comment: Your code is not authenticating the user, which means that with only this snippet the user is unauthorized and the error message is expected. Please provide the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance() ;  
if(mAuth! =null)   
{  
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();  
mDatabase.child( "UsersProfile").child(key).setValue(userProfile);  
}
```

This is the code which i use to save userProfile in my firebase database.